# Free Basic Hosting w SSL Certificate

Tags: web-hosting, https, free

I'm looking for a free hosting provider which provides an SSL Certificate at no additional charge. Does anyone know of a hosting provider which can provide such a service?

Thanks in advance,

Amani Swann

Comment: Sorry but we don't allow these types of questions, we have a catch all and if you can't find the answer in there its because no one else has replied with one. Also if your serious about security SSL why look for a free one? shared/free hosting is hardly secure to begin with. please look in the question linked, otherwise use our chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is simply for testing purposes during the development process - it will be moved to an internal server once the development process is complete - it is simply a proof of concept at this time.

Comment: Ah right I see, my advice would be to ask in our chat channel. We don't allow such questions because we have the catch all question and generally these type of questions get spammed.